# PDF.JS Example Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, pdf.js

I have a simple HTML file that works in both Safari and Windows based browsers.

When I embed the HTML logic into a software tool (Claris FileMaker) and try to display this through their internal browser, I get mixed results.

For Windows through FileMaker, I get the expected result, the PDF displays.

For Mac the FileMaker, I receive the heading text and an empty black square. Which is the same end result I receive when parsing this to JSFIDDLE. The code returns two errors:

- SyntaxError: Unexpected private name #setAnnotationCanvasMap
- TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions')

I realise I am barking up a unique tree here. I'm hoping someone has the knowledge to lend some assistance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <base href="https://mozilla.github.io">

        <style>#the-canvas {
  border:1px solid black;
}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

        <h1>PDF.js 'Hello, world' example</h1>

        <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">// atob() is used to convert base64 encoded PDF to binary-like data.
// (See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/
// Base64_encoding_and_decoding.)
var pdfData = atob(
  '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');

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Using DocumentInitParameters object to load binary data.
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');

  // Fetch the first page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');

    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.promise.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on an iPad running iOS 14.8. It seems like Safari 14 on MacOS/iOS doesn't support private class methods based on the browser compatibility chart on MDN. You can update your OS to get Safari 15 or use the legacy build of pdf.js library by following the instructions under Building PDF.js on their GitHub repo.

[MDN - private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_With_Private_Class_Features#browser_compatibility)

[pdf.js issue #14327](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/14327)

[Building PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#building-pdfjs)